# Linq - adding .Include(x=>Table) causes error 500

Tags: c#, linq

I have a fairly straightforward database schema. I have a list of Cemeteries, each Cemetery may have a CountryId for where it's located. The majority are currently null. I am attempting to return a paged result.

If I do the below, it works perfectly fine, fast and paged. If I use the `.Include`, I can see the `List<T>` returned to the controller, and the controllers return sit to the API. The API however shows error 500.

```
public Shared.Models.Paging.PagedResult<Cemetery> List(int page, string filter)
{
    const int pageSize = 10;

    var data = _ctx.Cemeteries
                   // .Include(p => p.Country)
                   .AsNoTracking()
                   .AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter) && filter != "null")
    {
        data = data.Where(filter);
    }

    return data.GetPaged(page, pageSize);
}

public partial class Cemetery
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public int? CountryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public virtual Country? Country { get; set; }
}

public partial class Country
{
    public Country()
    {
        Cemeteries = new HashSet<Cemetery>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateTime? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Cemetery> Cemeteries { get; set; }
}
```

If I place a `try/catch` in the code, all I get is an error 500, the server did not indicate success.

```
public async Task<PagedResult<CemeteryModel>> List(int page, string filter)
{
    var searchParams = $"/{page}?filter=";

    searchParams += string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter) ? "null" : filter;

    return await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<PagedResult<CemeteryModel>>($"api/Cemetery/List{searchParams}");
}
```

Comment: Usually returning EF entities from controllers is not a good idea. Using ViewModels would be better. And the error you are probably getting is a serialization error. Because EF entities usually have cross-references, serializing those is a problem in default. You can change the general serialization settings to ignore them or you can use ViewModels as best practices say.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 means that there was an exception on the server, so you would need to debug the server code, not the client code (which is what you are doing at the moment).

Having said that, if `filter` is a string, then I'm surprised hat the following even compiles...

data = data.Where(filter);

...as, [as far as I can see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-7.0), `Where` doesn't have an overload that takes a string.

However, debugging the server code should reveal exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was I had a mapping issue in my controller from Cemetery to CemeteryModel

What I had

```
  CreateMap<Cemetery, CemeteryModel>().ReverseMap();
```

What I needed

```
  CreateMap<PagedResult<Cemetery>, PagedResult<CemeteryModel>>().ReverseMap();
```